# How to access intent parameters inside Android Chrome web application

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, mobile

We have a 'launcher' application on our android devices that can launch web applications. You log in in the 'launcher', then you receive a list of web applications you are allowed to access. When clicking on them, they are launched with an intent in kiosk mode.

It is possible to send parameters with an intent, but my question is: is it possible to access those parameters in the web application itself? So for instance a key that is received from the server when logging in in the launcher app is then sent to the web application in Chrome as a parameter in the intent and can then be used in API calls in the web applications.

Can they be added to the window object, or something like that? And if yes, how would I do that?